# Alarms Sounds/Songs

Tags: music, music-player, alarm, google-play-music

Am I able to set my alarm sound as a song I have downloaded (either Google Play music or a third party music downloader) instead of the preset "sounds"? I have a files explorer already installed if needed.
Thanks.

Comment: Which phone do you have?

Comment: Actually in my phone I can set The Ringtone of my phone as a Alaram Tone..So when I want to use some dow loaded mp3 as alaram I first make it as ringtone than set it as alaram tone and than remove it as ringtone.

Comment: Using motorola moto G. My alarm tones can be viewed in settings as "default notification alarms". How do I make downloaded mp3 a notification alarm/ringtone?

Comment: Don't worry I just got an app that does ringtones and alarms

Comment: Cool..now you can add this in answer section and accept your own answer by upvoting so that in future if someone is facing same problem can get solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the app ringtone maker. Make the alarm/ringtone, save it and select it as the sound.